# Prevent Double Form Submit using Tokens

Tags: php

I am trying to prevent the user from double submitting the forum by adding token hidden field.

So here is what I have done so far (before the forum loads I have this code to create a token with the current time as a value.

```
$token = time();
setcookie('formToken', $token, time() + 3600);
```

in my forum I have a hidden input like this

```
<form method="post" action="'.$PHP_SELF.'?action=update">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="'.$token.'" />
<input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

now on the top of my page where $action == "update" I have this code

```
if(isset($_POST)  &&  ($_POST['token'] != $_COOKIE['formToken'])){
    $error_list .= '<li>You can not submit this forum twise.</li>';
}
```

if i hit F5 to refresh the page it submit the form again without displaying my error.

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment. Why don't you redirect to a "form submitted" page after the form submission so that F5 won't repost the form? phpbb does exactly like this (try to post something and press F5 - no luck).
Or you can use Ajax...

Comment: So The user see the result of the first submitting on the screen.

Comment: @DyllenJamesOwens I got no reputation for that edit.

Comment: @Mike: this is not incompatible with what I said.

Comment: @Mike What he's saying is have the form POST to a results page instead of the same page. That page could also show the results.

Comment: @ChristianStewart : not really. I'm saying to post to a page (even the same one) that redirects to the results page (that is F5-safe). This is the phpbb way.

Comment: @gd1 Ah I see what you're saying, yes this would work OP

Comment: I see. but what is the benefit of doing so?

Comment: @Mike This would prevent re-submit on refresh because it would be a completely different page.

Comment: You have a F5-safe page without the need of doing weird things (like the token stuff)

Comment: So if I redirect the user to a different page will solve my issue? so insted on <form method="post" action="'.$PHP_SELF.'?action=update">  change to <form method="post" action="new_file.php">

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST)`

Try that, instead of using isset check for the _POST being empty.

Comment: write that token into your db and check before re-inserting.

Comment: Possible duplicate at this point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901696/what-are-some-methods-to-prevent-double-posting-in-a-form-php?rq=1

Answer (score 11):

I suggest you to use use the [**PRG pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (Post/Redirect/Get), which is also implemented by forums like `phpbb`.

> Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) is a web development design pattern that
> prevents some duplicate form submissions, creating a more intuitive
> interface for user agents (users). PRG implements bookmarks and the
> refresh button in a predictable way that does not create duplicate
> form submissions.

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/PostRedirectGet_DoubleSubmitSolution.png]

Comment: I am confused. should i implement ajax/jQuery submit behind the sean? or when a user click submit button redirect them to a page that does the post and then it redirect them back to where they have started?

Comment: Post to the page #1 that makes a redirect via header("Location: something"); to the page #2. The page #2 will show the results of the submission process (how? depends on your logic and where/how data is stored and retrieved). If the user refreshes the page #2, results will be shown again without reposting.

Comment: It will prevent "some" duplicates yes, but if there is any delay between your user click and redirect this "pattern" becomes useless without other measures.

Comment: Compliment PRG pattern with $_SESSION (session). 1. Check if the session is there 2. If yes, prevent user from submitting, if no, create the session before you do any processing, so if the double/triple/so on.. clicks happened, at least your data will not get double processed 3. Unset the session when all the process completed

Comment: But this can't protect you from the user pressing the "Back" button of the browser and submitting again, right?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just set a session when the form is successfully submitted?

so `$_SESSION['submitted'] = 1`;

Then you can check for it.

Or Do

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])  &&  ($_POST['token'] != $_COOKIE['formToken'])){
    $error_list .= '<li>You can not submit this forum twice.</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

gd1 answer will not prevent double click submission or accidental double submit by various jQuery bindings on a complex javascript form code.

Double click may be even faster then disabling submit button, or hiding it with javascript, so this would not be a full answer either.

The session token will not work either because session is not yet written and thus available or updated for the second process which may be just milliseconds away sharing the same session ID. The session is stored only upon completion of the fist process.

Cookie technique could be an answer as far as both processes are able to communicate over cookie in a blocking way, which may result to the same problems as the session sharing above.

The best solution would be to use server's shared memory access to check if the other process had already processed the data (order, payment, etc..) with the pregenerated data hash, or use database table blocking select and insert to check if the pregenerated hash has been already submitted.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion 1)**

on Successful Submission Delete the cookies  (removeTokens)

```
    function removeToken()
{
    //set formToken cookie val to "" (or any default xxxx) and the past expiry date for it 
    setcookie("formToken", "", time()-3600);
    //try to unset - this is not needed ,we may try it
    unset($_COOKIE['formToken']);
}
```

ie simply on your page if(isset($_POST)) removeToken();

**Suggestion 2)**

Perform a redirect as suggested by Tom Wright here [Avoiding form resubmit in php when pressing f5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722547/avoiding-form-resubmit-in-php-when-pressing-f5)

```
 header('Location: formsubmitSucess.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this way of preventing double form submissions, it has worked on all occasions so far. Let me know if you need additional questions as this tutorial assumes you have intermediate knowledge on database and PHP.

STEP 1 : add a field on your database like this:
replace YOUR-TABLE with the name of your database table.

```
    ALTER TABLE `YOUR-TABLE` ADD `token` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER    `creationtoken`, ADD UNIQUE (`token`) ;
```

STEP 2 on your form page you add this to the very first line:
it will create a unique toke that will be inserted into your database table along with you query, so that it can be checked for later to make sure no other like it is submitted into your database, meaning no double form submissions.

```
    <?php 
    session_start(); 
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
    $_SESSION['token'] = md5(session_id() . time());
    ?>
```

then just before your submit button add this:

```
    // add this before the submit button
    // this will post the unique token to the processing page.

    <div style="width:100%; color:#C00; font-weight:normal;">Session Token: <?php echo strtolower($_SESSION['token']) ?></div>     

    <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="<?php echo  $_SESSION['token']?>" />
    // add this before the submit button


    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
```

STEP 3: now on your process.php page

```
    //this is where all of your form processing takes place.

    // this is where you call the database
    // if you need the database file let me know...
    include("../common/databaseclass.php");
    $db= new database();

    //here the token is posted then the database table is checked and 
    //if the form has already been added it will return a 1 and will 
    //cause the query to die and echo the error message. 

    $token = $_POST['token'];
    $query = "SELECT token FROM YOURTABLE WHERE token = '$token' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($num>0) {die('your form has already been submitted, thank you');}


    else {

    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "user";
    $pass = "password";
    $db_name = "database";

    mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    @mysql_select_db($db_name) or die( "Unable to select database");


    // table query      
    $sql1="INSERT INTO YOURTABLE (
    `token`,
    `user`,
    `email`,
    `password`,
    `newaccount`,
    `zipcode`,
    `city`,
    `state`,
    `country`,
    `telephone`,
    `creationip`,
    `createdaccount`
     ) 
     VALUES (
     '$token',
     '$username',
     '$email',
     '$password',
     '$newaccount',
     '$zipcode',
     '$city',
     '$state',
     '$country',
     '$phone',
     '$ipadress',
     '$createdaccount'

       )";

    $db->query($sql1);
    header("location:" http://home.php ");      

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the same issue I made a code to use it for my own stuff. It has the PRG pattern and flexible to use it on same page or with extern PHP file for redirection - Easy to use and safe, maybe this might help you.

```
class unPOSTer {

        private 
            $post = "KEEP_POST";

        public function __construct(string $name = null) {
            if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, "5.4.0") >= 0) {
                if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
                    session_start();
                }
            } else {
                if (!$_SESSION) {
                    session_start();
                }
            }
            $this->post = $name;
        }

        public function unPost() {
            if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
                session_start();
            } elseif (strcasecmp($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"],"POST") === 0) {
                $_SESSION[$this->post] = $_POST;
                header("Location: " . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?" . $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
                exit;
            } elseif (isset($_SESSION[$this->post])) {
                $_POST = $_SESSION[$this->post];
            }
        }

        public function retrieve($data) {
            if (isset($_SESSION[$this->post])) {
                $posts = @$_SESSION[$this->post][$data];
                if (isset($posts)) {
                    return $posts;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } 
        }

        public function reset() {
            if (isset($_SESSION[$this->post])) {
                unset($_SESSION[$this->post]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then use it like this:

```
<?php
    require_once "unPOSTer.class.php";
    $unpost = new unPOSTer();
    $unpost->unPost();
?>
<form action='' method=POST>
    <input type=text name=fname value="<?php echo $unpost->retrieve("fname"); ?>" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type=text name=lname value="<?php echo $unpost->retrieve("lname"); ?>" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input type=submit name=send value=Send>
</form>
<?php echo $unpost->reset(); ?>
```

Not much to configure, do it on every page you send form data if you like. The `retrieve()` method spits out the data you have sent, in case if you might go back and fix something. Feel free to fork/pull it at my [GitHub](https://github.com/thielicious/unPOSTer) page I added 2 demos there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here is a simple fix:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['form_token']) && time() - $_SESSION['form_token'] < 3){
    $data['message'] = 'try again later';
    return;
}
$_SESSION['form_token'] = time();
```

In my case the PRG pattern didn't have any effect since form submitted multiple times at the same time and the code had not been executed and there is no data saved to compare it against.